# requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) before the setContentView()

Tags: android

I want to know why the `requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` needs to use before `setContentView()`.

When I use this code and `setContentView()`, my application dies.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in setContentView we are setting the layout.Once it is done we cannot add features like FEATURE_NO_TITLE. We have to set these features before setCintentView() or else your application will crash when loading this page.

Comment: I can't express by English clearly. Thanks your answer.